# ServiceReference not fetching the all class names for activation

Tags: java, aem, crx

I'm using the below code to fetch the all reference classes in-order to activate it :

```
String filter = "(component.factory=com.requestclasses.mypack)";
bundleContext = componentContext.getBundleContext();
ServiceReference[] references = bundleContext.getAllServiceReferences(ComponentFactory.class.getCanonicalName(), filter);
```

But in **reference** i'm not getting all the classes.I'm not sure whether the issue is with code or **AEM 5.6** .
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally wouldn't recommend querying for service references using low level APIs like these.

You might be better off retrieving those references using the `@Reference` annotation like so:

```
@Reference(
   name = "componentFactories",
   referenceInterface = ComponentFactory.class,
   cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL_MULTIPLE,
   policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC
)
protected List<ComponentFactory> componentFactories = new ArrayList<ComponentFactory>();
```